# Printer is on 192.168 network while computers are on 10. network

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have a Shaw Bluecurve router (they "upgraded" me a year or so ago") and I recently got a Dell E525w laser printer. I am able to find the proper network that all my PCs are on "111 Basement-24" - I enter the passphrase and it connects dutifully.

However, because its IP is 192.168.1.16, and my computers are all things like 10.0.0.218, and as a result they are entirely unable to find the printer. I've tried plugging the printer into the ethernet port but it insists on being configured on a 192.168 network, even if I disable the wireless.

I can't seem to resolve this, it's the only device I have that puts itself on the wrong network. Is there anything I can do? I really need this network enabled printer to support the various devices in my house!

Comment: Do a hard reset of the Printer, back to factory specifications. Restart the printer (I think it should restart on hard reset). Now connect it by Ethernet to your network. It should pick up a 10. address the same as your devices and then be seen by your devices.

Comment: Is this a second-hand printer with its IP address hard coded? In that case, set it to DHCP from the front panel menu.

Comment: @John  Okay that's crazy I didn't think of that... but yes that worked. The keyword was knowing that "Factory Reset" isn't in the list, but "Initialize NVM" was. If you make an answer with that I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: I posted an answer for you. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a hard reset of the Printer, back to factory specifications. Restart the printer (I think it should restart on hard reset).

Now connect it by Ethernet to your network. It should pick up a 10. address the same as your devices and then be seen by your devices.

I see that this has helped you

Comment: I should note that this menu simply did not have a "factory reset" option - however, I was able to use "Initialize NVM" on the network menu and that is what made it happen. I suspect hdondt's comment about a hard coded IP is correct, but setting it in DHCP did not work for some reason - it just reverted back to its old one. Putting this in case some sorry sap has the same problem I had.